# Count longest streak of >0 in a Python list Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of float values, something like [-2.4, -1.3, -3.8, -1.9, 5.0, 0.6, 2.9, 1.9, 4.7, 3.5, 6.9, 1.5, -4.2, 3.7, 2.1, 6.6, 7.0, -4.6, -4.9].

What I need and trying to do is **count the longest streak** of values >0.

Tried doing it through for loop, but it gives only a total count, and through `itertools.groupby`, but I'm still getting only values.

```
for i, x in groupby(mintemps):
    if float(i >= 0):
        print(len(list(x)))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `print([i for i in lst if i > 0])` ?

Comment: Hey. Welcome to SO. Could you add the output you are trying to get?

Comment: it only prints values in the list that are >0. There may be odd <0 in this list, so I need to count the longest streak of values >0, not their total count.

If you look at the list above, the right answer would be 8, while this one-liner yields  12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `numpy` and `itertools` this turns out to be pretty fast ,

I converted the list to a boolean array in which the values are indicated if an element in greater than  0 and thne fed it to itertools.groupby to get its maximum consecutive value , the bit value is `True` or `False`.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
narr=np.array([-2.4, -1.3, -3.8, -1.9, 5.0, 0.6, 2.9, 1.9, 4.7, 3.5, 6.9, 1.5, -4.2, 3.7, 2.1, 6.6, 7.0, -4.6, -4.9])

def max_runs_of_ones(bits):
    maxvalue=0
    for bit, group in itertools.groupby(bits):
        if bit: 
            maxvalue=max(maxvalue,sum(group))
    return maxvalue
print(narr)

print("maximum value is",max_runs_of_ones(narr>0))
```

OUTPUT

```
[-2.4 -1.3 -3.8 -1.9  5.   0.6  2.9  1.9  4.7  3.5  6.9  1.5 -4.2  3.7
  2.1  6.6  7.  -4.6 -4.9]

maximum value is 8
```

Comment: works as intended using the tools I couldn't figure out in the first place, also pretty explanatory. Much appreciated!

Comment: I had some panda series that I wanted to extract the longest streak from and this worked perfectly for me, thanks for posting this... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = [-2.4, -1.3, -3.8, -1.9, 5.0, 0.6, 2.9, 1.9, 4.7, 3.5, 6.9, 1.5, 3.7, 2.1, 6.6, 7.0, -4.6, -4.9]


l=[]
z=0
for i in a:
    if i > 0:
        z=z+1
    else:
        l.append(z)
        z=0
```

Then the `max(l)` will be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) method takes a `key` argument to specify a function to compute key value for each element. We can use this to create a one-liner:

```
max(len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(mintemps, key=lambda x: x > 0) if k)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do the following. Removing the max will get you all the length of positive numbers sequences:

```
np.max([ len(l) for l in ("".join(["p" if i>0 else 'n' for i in a]).split('n')) if l])
```